# jquery: creating a custom dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery

I have created a custom drop-down menu using jQuery and CSS and it all works fine.

However, I have one issue that I cannot find a solution for.

Currently, I can select the Options `(Option 1, Option 2, etc...)` and I can also, `de-select` them by clicking on my selection.

When an option is selected, I change the drop-down menu `background:` and its `color:` and I add a `checked icon` to it so the user can see that they have selected something...

However, because I allow the users to `de-select` their options, I need to be able to change the `background:` and the `color:` and remove the `checked icon` IF there are no selections under that particular dropdown.

To explain this better, I have created this working FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/okmpxkcu/3/

If you click on the drop-down menus, you can select different options and then you can de-select them again.

I need the drop-down menu to go back it's original background color etc if there are no selections made.

Do help me if you understand

Comment: So do it homes!  When you unselect something, count how many children of the parent are selected.  If 0, revert the changes to the parent.

Comment: @Taplar, I have the same elements with the same class names all over my page. I can't count them like that.

Comment: You don't count them all over the page.  You count the ones inside the parent related to the one you unchecked.  Just like you are conditionally applying a change to only the parent of the elements when checked.  You conditionally apply your count logic to that parents children

Comment: that is what i meant. All the parents and their children have the same class names. I don't get how I can select just 1 of the parents and differentiate them.

Comment: Because only one element is being handled in that event.  That one element has one parent.  `$(this).closest('.buildExMain')` .  You have to think about your lookups contextually, not globally.

Comment: I understand that. However, i don't understand how I can count the de-selected elements so i can then use the `$(this).closest('.buildExMain').css{}` on its parent if all have been deselected....

Comment: All the children have the 'pSelection' class on them, right?  And their parent is the 'buildExMain' which we can get to by the `closest()` method.  Off of that guy we can do a find for those children, where they have or don't have your added class.  If zero of them have the added class, none are selected, right?  `$(this).closest('.buildExMain').find('.pSelection.added').length === 0`  Comprende?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) count all the `<p>` with the class `added`, if the `length` is greater than zero add the green background else remove the background.

```js
var cou = 0;
var myI = 0;
var videoSource = [];
$("div.buildExMain").find('i.fa').hide();

$(document).on('click', '.buildExMain', function(e) {
    $('.buildExDrop').hide();
    $(this).children('.buildExDrop').show();
});

$(document).on('click', '.pSelection', function(e) {
    //        console.log($(this).parent().children());
    var vidToAdd = $(this).attr("data-id");

    ///check if its added/////
    if ($(this).hasClass("added")) {
        $(this).removeClass("added");
        $('.fa-check:last-child', this).remove();
        $('.buildExDrop').hide();
        e.stopPropagation();

        videoSource = videoSource.filter(x => x != vidToAdd);

        console.log(videoSource);
    } else {

        $('.exHolder').addClass('buildExMain');
        $(this).addClass('added');
        $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');


        videoSource.push(vidToAdd);

        var videoCount = videoSource.length;

        console.log(videoSource);

        if ($(this).hasClass("exc")) {
            cou++;
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.buildExDrop').hide();

    }
    // check if p tags with added class exists
    if ($(this).parent().find('p.pSelection.exc.added').length > 0) {
        $(this).closest("div.buildExMain").find('i.fa').show();
        $(this).closest('.buildExMain').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).closest("div.buildExMain").find('i.fa').hide();
        $(this).closest('.buildExMain').removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

```css
.exHolder {
    width: 100%;
    color: #e91e62;
    border: solid 1px #e91e62;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.buildExDrop {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 1px #e91e62;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.pSelection {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
.pSelection:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-check-circle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    top: 4px;
    display: none;
}
.fa-check {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
.selected {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="exHolder buildExMain"><span>Select Options</span><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="buildExDrop">
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="1">Option 1 </p>
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="2">Option 2 </p>
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="3">Option 3 </p>
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="4">Option 4 </p>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="exHolder buildExMain"><span>Select Options</span><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="buildExDrop">
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="1">Option 1 </p>
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="2">Option 2 </p>
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="3">Option 3 </p>
        <p class="pSelection exc" data-id="4">Option 4 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```